# pass the pointer of image buffer to OpenCV and change the saturation?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to pass the pointer of my image buffer, change the saturation and see the result immediately. But the change is not applying in my buffer and it is not changing.

```
void changeSaturation(void* buffer,int width, int height)
{
  Mat matObject(width, height, CV_8UC4, buffer);
  m_matSource = matObject;
  Mat newMat = m_matSource.clone();

  // BGR to HSV
  cvtColor(matSource, matSource, CV_BGR2HSV);
  for(int i = 0; i < newMat.rows; ++i)
   {
     for(int j = 0; j < newMat.cols; ++j)
     {
        newMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 255; //saturationValue;
     }
   }

// HSV back to BGR
 cvtColor(newMat, m_matSource, CV_HSV2BGR); // here m_matSource->data change
```

}

How can I apply the change on my buffer?

Comment: from your code it is unclear what changes are you trying to make to the data pointed by `buffer`. What are you trying to do? What is `m_matSource` and where is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code when trying to reproduce your problem and in the process I fixed it. You cloned your source into newMat then changed the color space of your original image and then proceed to completely ignore your new modified image. Try this out:

```
void changeSaturation(Mat& image)
{
    Mat result(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());

    // BGR to HSV
    cvtColor(image, result, CV_BGR2HSV);
    for(int i = 0; i < result.rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < result.cols; ++j)
            result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 255; //saturationValue;
    }

// HSV back to BGR
    cvtColor(result, result, CV_HSV2BGR); // here m_matSource->data change

    namedWindow("Original");
    imshow("Original",image);

    namedWindow("Duplicate");
    imshow("Duplicate",result);
}


int main()
{
    Mat image;

    image = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");

    changeSaturation(image);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

**Edit**

To modify the input image:

```
void changeSaturation(Mat& image)
{
    // BGR to HSV
    cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2HSV);
    for(int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 255; //saturationValue;
    }

    // HSV back to BGR
    cvtColor(image, image, CV_HSV2BGR); // here m_matSource->data change
}
```

**Next Edit**

This now has (almost) the original function signature:

```
void changeSaturation(uchar* buffer, int rows, int cols, int type)
{
    Mat image(rows, cols, type, buffer);
    Mat result;
    // BGR to HSV
    cvtColor(image, result, CV_BGR2HSV);
    for(int i = 0; i < result.rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < result.cols; ++j)
            result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 255;
    }

    // HSV back to BGR
    cvtColor(result, image, CV_HSV2BGR);
}

int main()
{
    Mat image;

    image = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");

    changeSaturation(image.data, image.rows, image.cols, image.type());

    imshow("Original",image);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: Here you create new result Mat. But I want to change the buffer of passed image.

Comment: I update the answer to modify the input image. I'm not passing the buffer directly - but as you showed in your original code it's easy to create a Mat from a buffer, width and height.

Comment: @Perer R, thanks for answer! I tried also your solution before, but as I understood by calling cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2HSV); method, image's buffer changes and it refers to new memory address. So the changes in for cycle don't affect on buffer which method receives.

Comment: Ok I moved back to your original signature - though I'm passing the type as well.

Comment: I tried your last edit code, but it doesn't affect on original image. Did you tried that code? Also, if I remove the cvtColor(image, result, CV_BGR2HSV); and cvtColor(result, image, CV_HSV2BGR); methods, the original image also is changing. This means that cvtColor method creates new buffer as I guess.

Comment: Yes the image displayed at the end was modified. And when I comment out the 2 cvtColor() calls I get no change to my image at all. I suspect something else is going on in your code that I cannot see.

Comment: Thanks, it was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor `Mat matObject(width, height, CV_8UC4, buffer);` allocates `matObject` of size `width` and `height` at the location pointed by `buffer`.

In your function you are making changes to `newMat`, which is cloned from `matObject`. However, `buffer` doesn't point to `newMat`, it points to `matObject` and `matObject` is not changed by your function.